# Как подтянуть vendor?

Tags: php, yii2

Установил `yii2 basic` через композер, после сделал `composer install`  `composer update` - все прошло успешно!

Но проект не запускается - заметил что нет папки `vendor`!

Как после установки можно подтянуть еще и `vendor` ?

Comment: composer updatе. Но скорее всего вы что-то делаете не так при установке) добавьте **composer.json**

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас получилось размещение проекта в директории на подобии ".../my_project/basic" то нужно все файлы из папки basic переместить в my_project (где размещен composer.phar), заменив composer.json, и повторить команды php composer.phar install и php composer.phar update
После этого пустую папку basic можно будет удалить

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с такой проблемой, решение гораздо проще. Все дело в том что нужен php curl, установи его, и попробуй заного создать проект, и все будет отлично.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).